# menu bar with sub menu using css hover with link in mobile browser

Tags: css, menu, hover, anchor

i have a css menu bar that will show another div if you hover it, it is good if i view it on a computer browser, however i want to put an anchor tag to its main menu to redirect the user to its link but the problem is when it is viewed on a mobile browser you don't have a cursor to hover it so the user will definitely click the menu, the sub menus will not be displayed because the user is redirected already. how would i fix this problem? if i put a css hover in it, it will be clickable in mobile browser, i want to have it a link or make the anchor active if the sub menu of the current clicked menu is visible, am i going to use javascript on it? because i'm only using php right now.

i already a site that did it.. it is www.pcx.com.ph, when viewed in mobile at first click their menu will show the sub menu or drop down menu and if you click again the same menu you will be redirected to its page, how will i make something like that?

Comment: Are you open to using scripting to accomplish this?

Comment: yes, but i'm a newbie in scripting i just know the basics...